# Как убрать префикс .php

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте, нужно скрыть префикс *.php в url сайта (используя htaccess)

Тоесть было `url.ru/index.php` стало `url.ru/index`.

Только есть один нюанс, нужно скрыть не только для index.php, но и для всех остальных тоесть какой файл не был созан `url.ru/*.php` стало `url.ru/*`

Comment: Это не _префикс_, а _суффикс_ (ну или _постфикс_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делаем замену в `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Техподдержка хостинговых площадок и не обязана давать такие консультации (и не обязана знать такие подробности). По факту они всего лишь админы серверов.